# Git in WebStorm terminal suddenly began to print output in Russian language, what could it be?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm

**Git** in **WebStorm** terminal suddenly began to print output in Russian language, but in other terminals (I use **Mac**) **iTerm**, **built in terminal** it's OK, what could cause to it?

[image]

Comment: What does `echo $LANG` output in your terminal?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete, empty line in **Webstorm** and in other terminals it shows `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Sorry, executing `locale` probably does a better job at showing the current configuration. As for what could be the difference between the different terminals, I don't know.

Comment: This question and the answers there are probably worth taking a look: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/21096